# How to exclude non existent JSON data with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch-api

I'm using JavaScript Fetch to load some JSON data. I would like to display the data neatly in a HTML document.

I've had some troubles parsing some of the content. Most of the data objects I am trying to parse contain images, I need to load these. The problem arises when an object DOESN'T contain an image. What is happening at the moment is the first three images are loading (because they exist), then the fourth object doesn't have an image, and loop stops loading the rest (5th, 6th etc) of the images.

Can someone maybe take a look at this and give me nudge in the right direction?

```js
fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
    JSON.stringify(data);
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var listItem = document.createElement("li");
      var imgGrabber = document.createElement("img");

      listItem.innerHTML = data[i].title;
      imgGrabber.src = data[i].media[0].url;

      ul.appendChild(listItem);
      listItem.appendChild(imgGrabber);
    }


  });
```

So the issue arises when the fetch function comes upon the third object which contains no image. What do I need to do to make this loop grab only the images that exist, and skip empty objects? As it is now it's only loading the first three images and then stops.

I hope this makes sense let me know if I can improve this question.

Comment: what do you mean it "stops"? You mean you get an error? Can you show the difference in the JSON when there is or isn't an image in the object? Is it the case that the `media` property doesn't exist on those records, perhaps, or it's there but has no items in it? Probably you just need an `if` to check if that property exists in the JSON before trying to access it, I'd guess, but it's not really 100% clear based on the information available.

Comment: Try `imgGrabber.src = data[i].media && data[i].media.length ? data[i].media[0].url : "";` This prevents errors in case where `data[i].media` is `undefined` or an empty array.

Comment: use `if` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `if` check to see if the media, and image url exist. The error is probably caused by trying to access `url` on the missing `media[0]`.

```
if(data[i] && data[i].media && data[i].media[0] && data[i].media[0].url) {...}
```

The condition is evaluated from left to right, if `data[i]` is falsy (`undefined` in this case), it won't try accessing `data[i].media`, and so on.

Example:

```
fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var listItem = document.createElement("li");
      var imgGrabber = document.createElement("img");

      listItem.innerHTML = data[i].title;

      if (data[i] && data[i].media && data[i].media[0] && data[i].media[0].url) {
        imgGrabber.src = data[i].media[0].url;
      }

      ul.appendChild(listItem);
      listItem.appendChild(imgGrabber);
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm wrong but I guess there is just exception - can't get property 'url' of undefined. So maybe just add condition?

```
if(data[i].media) { // or data[i].media[0] - depends on JSON structure
   imgGrabber.src = data[i].media[0].url;
   listItem.appendChild(imgGrabber);
}
```